# Trigger alert in Prometheus if master and slave database server goes down

Tags: prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-operator, prometheus-node-exporter

I have 2 queries. If they match I need to trigger an alert but it is not working:

```
up {name="DEV-DB-1-EC2"} == 0 and up {name="DEV-DB-2-EC2"} == 0
```

I shutdown both servers but not getting data its says: `no data` as output.

If i run each query separately it works.

Long story short:

if both **master db (DEV-DB-1-EC2)** and **slave db (DEV-DB-2-EC2)** goes down I need to trigger an alert.

Can someone provide right syntax for this requirement?

Comment: I do not use Grafana. This is only a guess: `up{name="DEV-DB-1-EC2",name="DEV-DB-2-EC2"}=1` or `up{instance="DEV-DB-1-EC2",job="DEV-DB-2-EC2"}=1`

Comment: thanks for your reply, but above query is not working

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/12151). It will help you improve your question.

Comment: I think your title should be: Trigger alert in Grafana if Prometheus master and slave database goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Like every binary oprators in Prometheus [logical binary operators](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators) are subject to label sets match.

> vector1 and vector2 results in a vector consisting of the elements of
>   vector1 for which there are elements in vector2 with exactly matching
>   label sets.

In you case, the name obviously won't match so you need to add an [ON()/IGNORING()](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#one-to-one-vector-matches) clause.

A simple minimal fix is:

```
up {name="DEV-DB-1-EC2"} == 0 and on() up {name="DEV-DB-2-EC2"} == 0
```

You may want to refine it if you have multiple primary/secondary and need to match them.